# How do I unnest a list inside an R dataframe keeping both keys and values?

Tags: r, json, tibble, unnest

I'm currently working to extract data in JSON format into an R dataframe.

The data provided is of the following format:

[image]

Sample code to create test data:

```
test_input_data <- data.frame(date.x=c("2017-08-17", "2017-07-26", "2017-10-04"), properties.x=c("{\"gender\": \"Male\", \"nationality\": \"NZL\", \"document_type\": \"passport\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2018-07-05\", \"issuing_country\": \"NZL\"}", "{\"gender\": \"Female\", \"nationality\": \"NLD\", \"document_type\": \"national_identity_card\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2026-10-07\", \"issuing_country\": \"NLD\"}" , "{\"issuing_date\": \"2015-05-18\", \"document_type\": \"driving_licence\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2017-05-05\", \"issuing_country\": \"IRL\"}"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I would like to do is to create a dataframe as follows:

[image]

I'm currently using the RJSONIO::fromJSON() function to map properties.x into a list and then unnesting it:

```
properties_doc_reports <- test_data %>% 
  mutate(properties.x = map(properties.x, ~ RJSONIO::fromJSON(.))) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(purrr::map_lgl(properties.x, ~!rlang::is_empty(.x))) %>% ##this is optional as it deletes all rows with empty lists
  as_tibble %>% 
  unnest(properties.x)
```

However, this gets rid of the 'key' in properties.x which is what I also need. For reference, the output of the R code gives me the following:

[image]

However, each row in the input data does not have a consistent set of key value pairs so its not possible for me to infer the key from the row number. For example, 'gender' is missing from row 3) in the input dataframe

Any ideas?

Comment: The parse data looks a bit odd. Maybe try `jsonlite::fromJSON()` or `jsonlite::stream_in()`.

Comment: could you plese supply some example data

Comment: @JBGruber - I've used jsonlite and it gives me the same results.

Comment: @BertilBaron - test data added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is a quick solution. I am using the fact that the each json only contains one row. `map_df` from the package `purrr` then automatically converts all rows to a single data.frame. Since map_df keeps the row order is it just to bind the resulting df with the date column.

```
test_input_data <- data.frame(date.x=c("2017-08-17", "2017-07-26", "2017-10-04"), properties.x=c("{\"gender\": \"Male\", \"nationality\": \"NZL\", \"document_type\": \"passport\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2018-07-05\", \"issuing_country\": \"NZL\"}", "{\"gender\": \"Female\", \"nationality\": \"NLD\", \"document_type\": \"national_identity_card\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2026-10-07\", \"issuing_country\": \"NLD\"}" , "{\"issuing_date\": \"2015-05-18\", \"document_type\": \"driving_licence\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2017-05-05\", \"issuing_country\": \"IRL\"}"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
df <- bind_cols(
  test_input_data %>% 
    select(date.x),
  test_input_data$properties.x %>% 
    map_df(jsonlite::fromJSON)
)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Bertil, it does! I used the melt function after to 'unpivot' the dataframe but this was the step i needed